# Обработка данных ооп подход

Tags: ооп, post, php

К примеру есть форма, которая посылает на сервер данные, для примера:

```
id, news_name, news_full, news_short, status, access, title, description, keywords.
```

Вот сервер получил данные, подскажите пожалуйста пример как их можно красиво обработать (ооп подход.)

В общем как можно избежать примерно вот такого кода:

```
// может прийти строка 
$id = (isset($id) && is_numeric($id)) ? (int)$id : 0;
$news_name = (isset($news_name) && $news_name) ? htmlspecialchars($news_name) : '';
$news_full = (isset($news_full) && $news_full) ? htmlspecialchars($news_full) : '';
$news_short = (isset($news_short) && $news_short) ? htmlspecialchars($news_short) : '';

....
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно написать простой класс валидации данных, создать статические методы и получать значения через них.

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/jcZqf5)

Answer (score 1):

Если приложение большое и сложное, лучше не изобретать велосипед, используйте фреймворки: [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), [Play](http://www.playframework.com/)